# Refresh public observable from service used in component

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are 3 files:

- AuthService that deals with login and logout
- TopbarComponent that contain the /login, /logout links
- topbar.component.html file used in the above component

My probleme is that i'm trying to make the isLogged variable in AuthService as an observable in order to "watch" it in TopbarComponent to make update the value in the html file in live.

I think it would work if I put the isLogged as an @Input() in the TopbarComponent but there has to be a better way.

**UPDATED FILES**

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

//
import {HttpService} from "./http.service";
import {LocalStorageService} from "./local-storage.component";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    public isLoggedIn:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        var user = this.localStorageService.getItem('user');
        this.isLoggedIn.next(!!(user && user.token));
    }

    login(email, password): Observable<boolean> {

        return this.httpService.call('post', 'login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                let token = response.json() && response.json().token;

                if (token) {
                    this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
                    // store email and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    this.localStorageService.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: token }));
                    // return true to indicate successful login
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // return false to indicate failed login
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
        // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
        this.localStorageService.removeItem('user');

    }

    signup(email, password): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.httpService.call('post', 'signup', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => (response.status === 201) ? true : false);
    }
}
```

**topbar.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
//
import {SearchBoxComponent} from "../search-box/search-box.component";
import {AuthenticationService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";

declare const module;

@Component({
    selector: 'topbar',
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [SearchBoxComponent],
    templateUrl: 'topbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['topbar.component.css']
})
export class TopbarComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private userService: UserService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(
            observer => console.log(observer))
    }

}
```

**topbar.component.html**

```html
<header class="topbar">
    <h1 routerLink="/">homepage</h1>
    <search-box></search-box>
    <a routerLink="/login" *ngIf="!(authenticationService.isLoggedIn | async)">Login</a>
    <a routerLink="/signup" *ngIf="!(authenticationService.isLoggedIn | async)">Signup</a>
    <a routerLink="/logout" *ngIf="(authenticationService.isLoggedIn | async)">Logout</a>
    <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {userbar:'userbar'}}]"
       *ngIf="(authenticationService.isLoggedIn | async)">{{userService?.user?.email}}</a>
    <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {userbar:null}}]"
       *ngIf="(authenticationService.isLoggedIn | async)">{{userService?.user?.email}}</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below,

**auth.service.ts**

```
  import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

  // change observable to subject
  public isLogged:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  // to set value use below
  this.isLogged.next(true);   //  this.isLogged.next(false);
```

in your template use `async` pipe.

**topbar.component.html**

```
 *ngIf="(authenticationService.isLogged | async)"
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work :( But thanks for the try! I'm trying to see how rxjs/store works. Maybe it can help me.

Comment: it does not work as in, not suited for your application or using Subject is not working? I tried it in plunker and works for me.

Comment: I've updated the first post so that you can check if i'm made a mistake.

Comment: Looks correct to me, can you create a Plunker for it? Is the subscribe firing in the topbar component?

Comment: I tried it here at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjqEmgLpLKS6vhXiefDA?p=preview), Changes are in auth service and app component

Comment: I agree, you plunker works. The only thing I can see is that my case seem more complicated. It could come from something else. I made a plunker with my modules but I can't make it work. I can't find errors so that I can fix them..(it's the first time I try to make one) http://plnkr.co/edit/021CK6DbbemnHXZWrXMn?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121391/discussion-between-jeremy-and-madhu-ranjan).

Comment: I've found the problem. In my login.module that is lazyloaded, I had in providers the AuthenticationService. So I had 2 instances of the services.. I just removed the one from the module and it works. Thanks to both of you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If initial idea was to check if user logged in or not, You can also try other option:

**AuthService**:

```
constructor(http: Http) {}
public isLoggedIn(): Observable<any> {
    var user = this.localStorageService.getItem('user');
    if(user){
        return Observable.of(true);  
    } else {
        // Also return Observable after call, where tokenAPiUrl is AbstractAPI
        return this.http.get('tokenApiUrl'); 
    }
}
```

***topbar.component.ts***

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticationService.isLogged().subscribe(
        observer => console.log(observer))
}
```

You can inject authService everywhere and check if user logged in or not and add some logic after user login credentials check.